# Is there a way to send attachement image to Salesforces server with Web to leads forms or Web to case & with using AJAX?

Tags: attachment, web2lead, fileupload, web-to-case

So what I am looking for in an indication, because all articles I read about when it comes to sending attachment are dealing with web to lead or web to case forms with default submission!

But what about sending this via AJAX ?
Because yesterday I have managed to submit a simple form without attachment using a proxy sever via a php script, but now adding images ? it seems to me too compilcated, especially that there is no way to do a simple direct submission of images to salesforce servers.

Has anyone faced this problem ? had an idea about how this can be solved ? is it possible anyway ?

You can check my previous question to understand more, now an image field has to be added ?

Any help would be too much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure Javascript, the following code should work with a couple preliminary steps.

1. You need to obtain an access token
2. The file data needs to be a base64 encoded string

#### To attach a file to a Salesforce record:

```
    // ParentId is the SObject of the record you're attaching a file to
    // body truncated for brevity; replace with base64 of your file
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "ParentId":"0013i0000033JjN",
        "Name":"test.pdf",
        "body":"MY_BASE_64_STRING"
    });
    
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if(this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    });
    
    // Replace MY_ACCESS_TOKEN with your access token
    xhr.open("POST", "https://na112.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Attachment/");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    
    xhr.send(data);
```

#### To get the base64 string of the file

You can use something as follows to get the base64 string of the file with a simple html form and some jasvascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<style>
</style>

<body>
    <input id="file" type="file" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="button">Evaluate
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var files = document.getElementById('file').files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
            getBase64(files[0]);
        }
    });

    function getBase64(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
            // reader.result is the base64 string of your file
            console.log(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        };
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/nx50whLu/

#### To obtain a Salesforce access_token

As for obtaining the `access_token` you will need to create a connected app in Salesforce, this is also assuming your Org has the REST API permission set enabled. That is much longer explanation but is detailed here:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/projects/build-a-connected-app-for-api-integration/create-a-connected-app

Comment: Hi friend Thanks for that, But I mentionned that I am using a proxy server, I mean a PHP script! 
I doubt that your code will work because of CORS origin problems !

Comment: CORS comes from the receiver side. It sounds like your request is going Request > Proxy > Salesforce then on the return trip the appropriate headers being sent back from Salesforce are being dropped somewhere in your Proxy server.

PHP can render HTML/Javascript in which case you can make it work if you involve a client side page.